# Simple alert command is firing twice. No button. No click

Tags: javascript

I have one line of JavaScript;

```
alert('test');
```

It's included through the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>;
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It fires the alert box twice. All browsers.

Why?

Is this normal?

Please!

Comment: We need more context. Do you have the full document?

Comment: Whichever function that it is in might have been bound twice. We need more code.

Comment: This one line is the full document.

Comment: No html tags? Really?

Comment: Post your entire HTML document then.

Comment: Sorry - I am very new to this. I know this must be the dumbest question on record.

Comment: <html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"></head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: O S%%. I see it. Two js links, Thanks. You're the best.

Comment: OK, this question can be closed or deleted?

Answer (score 0):

More code is needed to be sure (always list the full example) but while using Google Chrome try placing `debugger;` before your `alert('test');` call and you will be able to compare the call stacks from the first and second passes through the code. This should be enough information to help you figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You import the same `script` twice in your HTML, thus running it twice.  Remove one of the two `script` tags and you should be groovy.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

On a separate note - you don't need that semi-colon after the jQuery import.